# C# Code Analyzer for C, C#, C++ and Java.

Tags: c#, c++, c, clang-static-analyzer

Please are there any tools available that will parse my source code to enumerate all class and function dependency for my project (C, C#, C++  or Java) and save it in doc, XML or any other format? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use reflector:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

With this add-in:
http://code.google.com/p/xmi4dotnet/

Answer (score 0):

For .NET, check this out

http://www.ndepend.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Understand](http://www.scitools.com/index.php) will handle all those languages.  It's not free but a very good tool.  Not sure about generating XML, but it'll do a variety of reports.  It also supports perl plugins, so you could probably generate whichever format you need for the reports.